# How to sculpt in realtime?

Tags: sculpting

To see each brush stroke I first must switch to `Edit` mode, then back to `Sculpt` mode. How can I see a brush stroke in realtime?

[image]

[image]

[image: picture]

Comment: Please describe your scene. I can probably tell the shark is rigged and you are not in rest pose, but there are many things that may be hidden behind the surface,

Comment: Yes, the shark is rigged and probably not in rest pose. I didn't know the term rest-pose. I would be fine to first pose before sculpt in order to solve the problem.

Comment: No, a rest pose means all the bones are in the DEFAULT position. Meanwhile, does the model have any shape keys? I have had much frustration trying to sculpt on a shape key that was set to zero. Switch to the “basis” shape key if you have one.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard Thank you for clarification. There is only one basis shape key in the model. I've attached the model.